# gradle generate error when minifying the code

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, proguard, android-proguard

when i try to set the minifyEnabled to true and try to sync gradle file i receive the follwoing error:

```
Error:Cause: com/android/build/gradle/tasks/AndroidProGuardTask
```

why i am receiving this error and how to solve it, I cant enable proGaurd in Android Studio.

**build.gradle**:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Comment: just one line error or something else?

Comment: @VivekMishra only the posted error

Comment: You will need to change you progaurd-rules.pro depending on the libraries that you are using.

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi how can i do that

Comment: In the progaurd-rules.pro file you need to use rules like -keep or -downturn depending on the libraries, you can just do a search.

Comment: could you add --debug and --stacktrace to Command-Line Options, under Build... -> Build Tools -> Compiler and try recompile, this should show more infromations of what failed

Comment: Per the [documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-shrinking), please provide the details from the `resources.txt` file to help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

are you using any external library files in your project? If yes, the you need to add -keep in the proguard-rules.pro file.
I have added the following code to the file:

```
-keep public class org.jsoup.** {
    public *;
}
```

my proguard-rules.profile can be found [here](https://github.com/swathins079/key_job_search_/blob/master/app/proguard-rules.pro).
You can also make sure the error is because of this by disabling the minifyEnabled to false in the proguard-rules.pro file.

Comment: I modified the code in proguard-rules.pro and added the following line:-keep public class com.example.com.ecoassistant_04.Jama-1.0.3.jar {
    public *;
} where Jama-1.0.3.jar is the library i am using..but i still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

add this to your proguard

```
 -dontwarn package name of you library.**
```

in your case use package name of Jama

for example

```
-dontwarn org.slf4j.**
-dontwarn org.apache.log4j.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.**
```

if  you can paste more error or stacktrace I will try to help more